# How to specify only few fileds of an Entity need to be inserted with ReactiveCassandraRepository

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

With Spring Data, how do I specify to ReactiveCassandraRepository that, only few fileds of the passed Entity need to be inserted to Cassandra DB

For Example,

If my Entity is as follows,

```
@Table("employee_tb")
public class Employee {

    @PrimaryKey("emp_id")
    private int empId;

    @Column("emp_name")
    private String empName;

    @Column("emp_dept")
    private int empDept;

    @Column("emp_salary")
    private int empSalary;
    ........
    ........
    <Setters & Getters>
    ........
    ........
}
```

and my Repository is

```
public interface myCassandraRepo extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Employee, int>{

}
```

and if I want to insert a new record into DB with emp_id, emp_name and emp_dept (*excluding* **emp_salary**), what should I do..!!?

I tried

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setEmpId(1234);
emp.setEmpName("Test");
emp.setEmpDept(5);

myCassandraRepo.insert(emp);
```

As well as using save()

```
myCassandraRepo.save(emp);
```

In both cases new record is getting created in DB, but the field *emp_salary* also getting inserted with initialized value **0**, which I want to avoid.

How can I achieve this, please help

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data generally follows the rule that all non-null fields get written into the underlying database. In your case, `emp_salary` is a primitive value, hence it's non-null.

You have the following options to change the persistence behavior of individual properties:

- `@ReadOnlyProperty`: Use to mark a property as read-only. The property value is read from the database but not written.
- `@Transient`: Exclude a property entirely from being read or written.

Cassandra comes with some specifics that need to be considered in a persistence context. Since Cassandra has no means to generate a key, we cannot know whether a row already exists for the object to be saved. Therefore, Spring Data Casandra uses the upsert mechanism by issuing always an `INSERT` statement that contains `null` values. This is to make sure that if a row already exists, nulled fields get overwritten so that the object state is reflected in the database.

You can apply optimization in your code. If you know that your entity is new, then you can call `ReactiveCassandraRepository.insert(…)` which omits null fields.

See also the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.usage-annotations) for further reference.